# Second spinner not working

Tags: android

I have a problem with my second spinner not being able to select an item and save the value.

if I add `s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` my spinner wont select or scroll .
If i remove the listener the selection of items is enable but it doesn't catch the selection , can anyone tell me what I am missing ?

thanks

```
    public class MenuTiendas extends Activity implements
        OnItemSelectedListener{
    Spinner s1,s2,s3;
    String sp1, sp2, sp3 = "";
    String ID, id_pasajero = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menutiendas);
        s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        //s3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        //s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Sea_reg_app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ID = prefs.getString("ID", "");
        id_pasajero = prefs.getString("ID_own","");

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
        sp2= String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
        //sp3= String.valueOf(s3.getSelectedItem());



        Button siguiente = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button7);
        //Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        if(sp1.contentEquals("SUPERAMA")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL DE ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        }


        if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (COMER)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        }
        if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (FRESKO)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
        }
        if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (C.MARKET)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
        }
        if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (SUMESA)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL. HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
        }
        if(sp1.contentEquals("CHEDRAUI")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMENDRAS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter6.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter6);

        }

        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Log.d("LOG", "resultado sp1 " + sp1);
                Log.d("LOG", "resultado sp2 " + sp2);

                //leemos status de usuario y determinamos a donde ir.
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Sea_reg_app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("sp1", sp1.toString());
                editor.putString("sp2", sp2.toString());
                //editor.putString("sp3", sp3.toString());
                //cbMarcame1_1 = prefs.getBoolean("Guardar_Vincular",false);
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(new Intent(MenuTiendas.this, formulario.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Below is XML code of this activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dip"
        android:text="@string/lblAcc"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:entries="@array/tienda" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dip"
    android:text="@string/lblSubAcc1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dip"
    />
<Button
    android:text="Siguiente"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where did you set your Adapter for  spinner 1

Comment: I think it is better to assign a new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() to your spinner2 since you should want a different onItemSelected response because spinner1 is only used to give different entries list to spinner2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check for the id, which is firing inside onItemSelected listener to make it work.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                           long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
            if(sp1.contentEquals("SUPERAMA")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("ACE RELL DE ALMNDRS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL DE AJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
                list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

            }


            if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (COMER)")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL DE PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL DE PINA (FCO)");
                list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (FRESKO)")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
                list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (C.MARKET)")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL DE DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
                list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (SUMESA)")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL. HIGO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
                list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("CHEDRAUI")) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("ACE RELL ALMENDRAS (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
                list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
                list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                dataAdapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter6.notifyDataSetChanged();
                s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter6);

            }

            break;

        case R.id.spinner2:
            sp2= String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
            break;
    }




    Button siguiente = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button7);

    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Log.d("LOG", "resultado sp1 " + sp1);
            Log.d("LOG", "resultado sp2 " + sp2);

            //leemos status de usuario y determinamos a donde ir.
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Sea_reg_app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("sp1", sp1.toString());
            editor.putString("sp2", sp2.toString());
            //editor.putString("sp3", sp3.toString());
            //cbMarcame1_1 = prefs.getBoolean("Guardar_Vincular",false);
            editor.commit();
           // startActivity(new Intent(this, formulario.class));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this part:

> if I add s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); my spinner wont select or
>   scroll . If i remove the listener the selection of items is enable but
>   it doesn't catch the selection

I tried to reproduce your error, but with your code, I can select or scroll `Spinner2`, but the content will remain the same. The reason for this one is because you don't specify for which `Spinner` your code inside `onItemSelected` for. So, if you select `Spinner2`, it will check the `Spinner1` and replace the data for `Spinner2`. That's why `Spinner2` is not updated when you select it. The following code will solve the problem.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                           long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sp1 = String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());
    sp2 = String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
    //sp3= String.valueOf(s3.getSelectedItem());


    Button siguiente = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    //Toast.makeText(this, sp1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (arg0.getId() == R.id.spinner1) {

        if (sp1.contentEquals("SUPERAMA")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add("ACE RELL DE ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        }


        if (sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (COMER)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
        }
        if (sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (FRESKO)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
        }
        if (sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (C.MARKET)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DE DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter4.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter4.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter4);
        }
        if (sp1.contentEquals("CITY FRESKO (SUMESA)")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMNDRS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL AJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PIMIENTO ROJO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL ARANDANOS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL DATIL DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL. HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PINA (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter5.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter5.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter5);
        }
        if (sp1.contentEquals("CHEDRAUI")) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("ACE RELL ALMENDRAS (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL COCO DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL HIGO (FCO)");
            list.add("ACE RELL PASAS DULCE (FCO)");
            list.add("AJO FINAS HIERBAS (FCO)");

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            dataAdapter6.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter6.notifyDataSetChanged();
            s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter6);

        }

    }

    siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Log.d("LOG", "resultado sp1 " + sp1);
            Log.d("LOG", "resultado sp2 " + sp2);

            //leemos status de usuario y determinamos a donde ir.
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Sea_reg_app", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("sp1", sp1.toString());
            editor.putString("sp2", sp2.toString());
            //editor.putString("sp3", sp3.toString());
            //cbMarcame1_1 = prefs.getBoolean("Guardar_Vincular",false);
            editor.commit();
            //startActivity(new Intent(MenuTiendas.this, formulario.class));
        }
    });
}
```

But, if I remove `s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);`, the code also works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate your `Spinner` inside `onItemSelected` method as:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
    if(adapterView.getId() == R.id.spinnerOneId){
        // your action  
        sp1= String.valueOf(s1.getSelectedItem());                  
    }
    else if(adapterView.getId() == R.id.spinnerTwoId){
       //your action
       sp2= String.valueOf(s2.getSelectedItem());
     }
}
```